# Error NDSolve::ndnum: when using shooting method

Tags: differential-equations

```
Eqn1 = f'''[x] + f[x] f''[x] + ((2 n)/(n + 1))(1 - f'[x] f'[x])- M f'[x]==0
Eqn2 = T''[x] + Pf[x] T'[x]-Pr ((2 p)/(n + 1)) f'[x] T[x] + (2 /(n + 1))[A f'[x] + B T[x]] == 0

BC1 = f[0] == 0;
BC2 = f'[0] == λ + β f''[0];
BC3 = f'[inf1] == 1;
BC4 = T[0] == 1 + σ T'[0];
BC5 = T[inf1] == 0;

param1 = {n -> 0, M -> 0, Pr -> 1, p -> 5.29387, A -> -0.05, 
   B -> -0.05, λ -> 0.5, β -> 0.5, σ -> 0.5};
inf1 = 1.5;

Sol1 = NDSolve[{Eqn1, Eqn2, BC1, BC2, BC3, BC4, BC5} /. param1, {f, 
    T}, {x, 0, inf1},

   Method -> {"Shooting","StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0]==0,f'[0] == 0, 
               f''[0] == 0, T[0] == 0, T'[0] == 0}}];

param2 = {n -> 1, M -> 0, Pr -> 1, p -> 5.29387, A -> -0.05, 
   B -> -0.05, λ -> 0.5, β -> 0.5, σ -> 0.5};

Sol2 = NDSolve[{Eqn1, Eqn2, BC1, BC2, BC3, BC4, BC5} /. param2, {f, 
   T}, {x, 0, inf1}, Method -> {"Shooting","StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, 
      f''[0] == 0, T[0] == 0, T'[0] == 0}}]

param3 = {n -> 1.5, M -> 0, Pr -> 1, p -> 5.29387, A -> -0.05, 
   B -> -0.05, λ -> 0.5, β -> 0.5, σ -> 0.5};

Sol3 = NDSolve[{Eqn1, Eqn2, BC1, BC2, BC3, BC4, BC5} /. param3, {f, 
   T}, {x, 0, inf1}, 

  Method ->{"Shooting","StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == 0,f'[0] == 0, 
      f''[0] == 1, T[0] == 0, T'[0] == 0}}]

Plot[{f'[x] /. Sol1, f'[x] /. Sol2, f'[x] /. Sol3, f'[x]}, {x, 0, 
  inf1}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {η, f' (η)},

 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Green, Blue, Yellow}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12], PlotRange -> All, 
 Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {η, f'}]
```

I got the error message

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0

from the above code. I do not understand it. Please, can you help with this?

Comment: That error usually means division by zero at `x == 0` in one of your equations, or that there are undefined parameters in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

When I change `Eqn2` to

```
Eqn2 = 
  T''[x] + Pr f[x] T'[x] - Pr ((2 p)/(n + 1)) f'[x] T[x] + (2/(n + 1)) 
    (A f'[x] + B T[x]) == 0;
```

and evaluate

```
Sol1 = 
  NDSolve[{Eqn1, Eqn2, BC1, BC2, BC3, BC4, BC5} /. param1, {f, T}, {x, 0, inf1}, 
    Method -> 
      {"Shooting", 
       "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
          {f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f''[0] == 0, T[0] == 0, T'[0] == 0}}]
```

[image: soln]

From that I conclude that your problems arise from simple syntax errors.

- using `Prf[x]` where you should write `Pr f[x]`
- using `[A f'[x] + B T[x]]` where you should write `(A f'[x] + B T[x])`